# How to connect two objects that communicate with each other?

Tags: design-patterns, coupling

I am writing a simple chat using Node.js, Websockets and Vue.js. Specifically, I have a Vue instance and a Websockets Client. When a user presses a "Submit" button, Vue asks the Client to send a message to a Server. When the Client receives a message from the Server, it asks the Vue to render it to the page. My first thought was for the Vue to have a reference to Client, and for Client to have a reference to Vue, but the two objects become closely coupled. Is there a better way to enforce communication between these two objects?

Comment: You don't need to hold two references; you only need to hold *one.*

Comment: Could you please provide some code? What did you try? Without details your issue sounds very abstract. However, I would use something like mediator pattern. It means you may have object that hold both references.

Comment: The Client only needs a "callback" to call after each server notification. The callback could be a standalone component or a Vue controller's method. `client.onEvent("xxx",callback())` or `client.onEvent("xxx", function(message){ })`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

- The `Vue` instance holds the reference to a `Client` instance.
- The `Client` instance is observed by an `ClientObserver` instance. The `Client` instance will push new event to its observer when it receive updates from the server.
- The `Vue` instance subscribes to the `ClientObserver` instance so that it will re-render every time a new event comes.

In this case, the `Vue` instance only keeps one reference to the `Client` instance and the `Client` instance only keeps on reference to the `ClientObserver` instance.

Comment: It could be worthwhile to consider both the inputs and outputs of the Client as reactive streams, in any case. So that rather than your `Vue` needing to know exactly how to tell it to send something, anything that needs to push to the server just shoves something on an observable, in the same way things watch an observable to get the updates